# What is develop license about AGPL license?

Tags: agpl-3.0

There are many good open source libraries which are under AGPL license. And sometimes on their official website, I see an license option named "development license". For example: https://www.onlyoffice.com/developer-edition-prices.aspx

It says this license allow others to develop with this open source project? I just cannot understand.

As under AGPL license, I think others have the permission to develop or integrate that open source project unless they release the product to public.

The link I give is not an exception, so could someone explain for me what does it mean?

Comment: Could someone tell me why this question is downvoted? I'm a newbee for this website but not for other stackexchange websites. I cannot notice what's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [their website](https://www.onlyoffice.com/developer-edition.aspx) makes clear, the product is dual-licensed, under [AGPL3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html) and a commercial license.

If you choose to use it under AGPL3, you (broadly) have permission to copy and/or change that code (strictly, to make a modified work) provided that when you distribute the work, whether modified or unmodified, or give access to it over a network, you do so under the terms of the AGPL.  This will broadly mean giving access to the full source and build environment of the work, and making it clear that this access is also under the terms of the AGPL.

The commercial option, as they say, is for people who require professional support with the product, and (presumably, though they don't say this) for those who wish to integrate the product into their own non-free software.  As ever, IANAL/IANYL.

Comment: So let's say if I want to integrate the product into one non-free software. But for now I am just **trying** to do it. I think the development is still under AGPL3 scope, and the release is under commercial license. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, provided you don't do anything during development that requires you to release code under AGPL3, at which point it may be hard to get your genie back into his bottle.  That would include letting people interoperate with your code over a network.